# What statistical test should I do for humpback whale singing behavior?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I am testing the preference of humpback whales singing at dark and twilight regimes vs. light.

For each 10 minute audio file is assigned the light regime and if there was song or nosong occurence.

My null hypothesis it would be something like: there is no preference to sing in one light regime

Here is my data : https://ualg365-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/a67963_ualg_pt/ESZwU858KllDvR3PcPfNnuABaPBEPsbnXIIoWguIhusVVA?e=uE8Bq8

I'm not sure about the right test to perform in R, so I will be very grateful if someone could give me a light on it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, your title is now better, thanks, but you should not reask the question, but edit the original!

Comment: ok, thank you for the suggestion